# Where GitLab build the application?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, continuous-delivery

Does someone know what Cloud engine is used by [GitLab CI](https://about.gitlab.com/features/gitlab-ci-cd/) to build the projects (even the private ones) you store in it?

I've started using it and it works fine. But I don't know where my code is running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://about.gitlab.com/2018/06/25/moving-to-gcp/: GitLab is moving from Azure to Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Yeah I realized that. But I want to know where they are (e.g. Digital Ocean, AWS, Heroku, etc...), got it?

Comment: I think you're not understanding what I'm saying. I'm saying that I'm using the online GitLab provider, I have no locally installation, I'm using the **Early Adopter** plan from gitlab.com

Comment: Ah, ok. I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a bonus, do you know anything about how secure is my code running on the cloud during the build?

Comment: I think secure enough. A lot of people build private code in clouds.